# Python - 'module' object has no attribute 'randrange'

Tags: python

I've 2 files a.py and b.py

**a.py**

```
from b import *

#and then some lines of code
```

**b.py**

```
import random
red = random.randrange(1,257) / 256.0

#and then some lines of code
```

While running I get an error saying `'module' object has no attribute 'randrange'`.

I dont know why this error is popping up because when I test it in some dummy file trying to print `red = random.randrange(1,257) / 256.0` , it works. But not in this case.

Why is this error popping up?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You've a third file, random.py. Rename it.

Comment: I already knew this and deleted the random.py file but pyc file got remained. Hence was getting the error.Thanks.

Comment: This is plainly stupid. Why, oh why, are there languages forcing me to rename my files? :(

Answer (score 3):

To confirm @ignacio 's answer you can run `python -v <script>`

This will list down all the importing modules and from where they are imported.