# I am not able to run this Python program

Tags: python

```
import random

for i in range(1,21):
    print("%10d" %(random.randrange(1,7)),

    if (i % 5 == 0):
         print ("")
```

What is wrong in this code ?

I know basic python (almost), but i am not able to figure out what could be error in this program.

it is showing this error:

Syntax Error: invalid syntax at line 6 (if statement)

## The fourth line is missing bracket .. Thanks all of you

Comment: still getting a error Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'randrange'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a right bracket )

```
print("%10d" %(random.randrange(1,7))),
```

would be correct

Comment: yes .. thanks all of you .. should i delete ? :P .. or let it stay ? ..the question?

Comment: still getting a error 
Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'randrange'

Comment: no its working fine for me.You haven't removed import random right?

Comment: no you shouldn't remove it..yeah sometimes even a ; makes one's life disastrous,where other people see it easily..so it helps:)

Comment: Bro .. still getting the same error ..:( ..Attribute Error

Comment: Done dude .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486334/python-module-object-has-no-attribute-randrange  .. related to this ..

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `)` before the last comma on line 4.

Comment: thanks :) .. should i delete this question ?

Answer (score 1):

Your parenthesis on line 4 don't match.  Because you have an unclosed paren, python doesn't report this syntax error until the colon on line 6 (python ignores line breaks as long as you are inside an enclosing set of parenthesis, brackets, or braces).

Comment: Thnks :) .. i totally missed that