# AttributeError when trying to use random.shuffle, after importing random?

Tags: python, random, shuffle, attributeerror

This code worked last night on my IDE Pycharm, but gives me this message when I try to run it now (have not updated or changed anything since then):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 5, in 
    random.shuffle(s)
AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'shuffle'

Here is the code I am running:

```
    import random

    digits = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
    s = [''.join([a,b,c,d]) for a in digits for b in digits for c in digits for d in digits]
    random.shuffle(s)
    real_password = '1234'
    i = 0

    for code in s:
if code == real_password:
    print()
    print('The password is: ', code)
    break
else:
    i += 1
    print(i, ' failures', end='\r')
```

Comment: Do you have a `random.py` file that might be getting imported instead of standard random? `print random` will tell you

Comment: *Very* related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20486334/5647260

Comment: @AndrewL. thanks i had a look :)

Comment: @slezica thank you this solved my problem! Don't I feel silly now that it was so simple :')